# Not sure how the hist function in MATLAB works

Tags: matlab

I am not very sure how the hist function in MATLAB works. I seem to have few problems with it.

Bascially, in the code below, i am trying to run the rotation invariant Uniform Local Binary Pattern(LBP) code. I have no problem with the LBP code but the problem is with hist function(indicated in the code below).

The problem is that the range i should get is from 0:9 but when i apply the histogram function i get values greater than 9 such as 35, 27 and even values such as 178114.Not very sure how to correct it.

```
I2 = imread('test.png');
RIUniformHist=[];
m=size(I2,1);
n=size(I2,2);
for i=1:10:m
    for j=1:10:n
        for k=i+1:i+8
           for l=j+1:j+8
             J0=I2(k,l);
             I3(k-1,l-1)=I2(k-1,l-1)>J0;
             I3(k-1,l)=I2(k-1,l)>J0;
             I3(k-1,l+1)=I2(k-1,l+1)>J0; 
             I3(k,l+1)=I2(k,l+1)>J0;
             I3(k+1,l+1)=I2(k+1,l+1)>J0; 
             I3(k+1,l)=I2(k+1,l)>J0; 
             I3(k+1,l-1)=I2(k+1,l-1)>J0; 
             I3(k,l-1)=I2(k,l-1)>J0;
             LBP=I3(k-1,l-1)*2^7+I3(k-1,l)*2^6+I3(k-1,l+1)*2^5+I3(k,l+1)*2^4+I3(k+1,l+1)*2^3+I3(k+1,l)*2^2+I3(k+1,l-1)*2^1+I3(k,l-1)*2^0;
             bits = bitand(LBP, 2.^(7:-1:0))>0;
             if nnz(diff(bits([1:end, 1]))) <= 2
                RIULBP(k,l)=abs(I3(k-1,l-1)-I3(k-1,l))+ abs(I3(k-1,l)-I3(k-1,l+1))+ abs(I3(k-1,l+1)-I3(k,l+1))+ abs(I3(k,l+1)-I3(k+1,l+1))+abs(I3(k+1,l+1)-I3(k+1,l))+abs(I3(k+1,l)-I3(k+1,l-1))+abs(I3(k+1,l-1)-I3(k,l-1));
             else
                RIULBP(k,l)=9;
             end
           end
        end
        RIULBP=uint8(RIULBP);
        RIULBPv=reshape(RIULBP,1,size(RIULBP,1)*size(RIULBP,2));   
        RIUHist=hist(RIULBPv,0:9); % problem
        RIUniformHist = [RIUniformHist RIUHist];
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post some simpler example code.

Answer (score 1):

The vector returned by

```
RIUHist=hist(data, bins)
```

is the count of how many elements of `data` are nearest the point identified by the `bins` vector.  So if you have a value of `178114`, that juts means that there were `178114` elements of `data` that were nearest to the matching index in `bins`.

You can use

```
[RIUHist, binsOut] = hist(data)
```

to let Matlab choose the bins (I believe it uses 20 bins) or

```
[RIUHist, binsOut] = hist(data, binCount)
```

To let Matlab choose the bins, but force a certain number of bins (I often use 100 or 200).

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.  I'm not sure what the LDB code is meant to do, and I cannot run your example code as is (I don't have 'test.png').  I was just trying to answer the specific question of why you could get a large value from hist when you were trying to create bins from 0 through 9.

Comment: then how to get values such that the values in RIUHist is between 0 to 9?