# How to extract LBP features from facial images in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

I'm not familiar with Local Binary Pattern (LBP), could anyone help me to know how to extract LBP features from facial images (I need a simple code example)?

While searching, I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509335/not-sure-how-the-hist-function-in-matlab-works), but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406314/local-binary-pattern-in-matlab

Answer (score 4):

1. So first of all you need to split the face into a certain amount of
   sections.
2. For each of these sections you then have to loop through the all of
   the pixels contained within that section and get their value (grey scale or colour values).
3. For each pixel check the value of the pixels which border it in (diagonals and up down left and right) and save them
4. for each of the directions check if the colour value of. if the colour is greater than the original pixels value you can assign that value a 1 and if it is less you can assign it as a 0.
5. you should get a list of 1's and 0's from the previous steps. put these numbers together and it will be a large binary number, you should be able to convert this to decimal and you will have a number assigned for that pixel. save this number per pixel.
6. after you have got a decimal number for each pixel within a section you can average all of the values to get an average number for this section.

This may not be the best description of how this works so [here](http://robinhsieh.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/LATP.png) is a useful picture which might help you.

Comment: Thank you @MrSansoms for your answer, I know how it works "logically" but I need simple example to create full view of LBP.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [extractLBPFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extractlbpfeatures.html) function in the R2015b release of the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB.

Comment: Hi @Dima. If I want apply it into 64x64 size image and segment into 16x16 size image block, I should add parameter (.., 'CellSize', [16 16]) is it? This mean I segmenting my image into 4x4 blocks? And if it is set to default, its mean I got the feature for one whole image, right?